# Data extraction with complex data patterns

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a legacy column in a database that has free form entries that I need to clean up into two separate columns: a `TYPE` and a `DATE` column. A sample of the data can be found below:

```
REMARKS
-------------------------------------
1CC 3/4/13 
04.25.14 (CC) SELF
3/13/14 1CC
COPY 9-28-12 
11/8/13 1CC SON REQUESTING
4/20/12 1CC
1 COPY 4-12-13 SELF
1CC 2/4/00, 11/17/11 WIFE REQUESTING
COPY 7-11-14
5.29.12 1CC HUSBAND REQUESTING
7/14/14 1CC
CC1-6/28/13 11/12/13 1CC
```

As you can see, there is hardly any consistency in the data except for the two factors of: there being "CC" or "COPY", along with a date. The format in which the dates were entered are also inconsistent, there might be multiple dates (of which I need to pull the first), and there is other garbage data scattered throughout that needs to be ignored.

Essentially I need to run through each row and look for 'CC' or 'COPY', along with the first date that has been entered. The desired output of the above would be as such:

```
TYPE (VARCHAR) | DATE (DATETIME)
--------------------------------
CC             | 03/04/2013
CC             | 04/25/2014
CC             | 03/13/2014
COPY           | 09/28/2012
CC             | 11/08/2013
CC             | 04/20/2012
COPY           | 04/12/2013
CC             | 02/04/2000
COPY           | 07/11/2014
CC             | 05/29/2012
CC             | 07/14/2014
CC             | 06/28/2013
```

This type of data extraction is something I am not all too familiar. I am thinking I need to use a complex combination of `SUBSTRING`, `CHARINDEX`, `LTRIM`, and `RTRIM`, but I've hit a complete mental block on how best to approach this. Any guidance on where I should begin would be incredibly helpful.

Please let me know if there's any further information I can provide, and thanks in advance.

Comment: Is this a one-time task, or do you have to do it (say) every day?

Comment: @PhilipKelley This will be a one time task. There are approximately 10,000 rows that will need to be extracted from.

Comment: Ouch. This is nearly an impossible task to be totally accurate with. Even in this small example there is tons of ambiguity. Since this is clearly user typed data even things like dateformat may be different. This is going to take some manual intervention to get it right when the rows are not perfectly consistent.

Comment: @SeanLange That's what I'm afraid of. I'm think there should be some sort of way to initially transform the entries based on how the date is entered. So first look at the date (is it separated like 10.15.15, 10-15-15, or 10/15/15), modify it into a consistent manner, and replace it over top of the previous entry and/or into a new column. That way at the very least I have one variable that is consistent. Would that be feasible?

Comment: Not really. This data is a total train wreck. You really don't have a decent way of even finding your CC or COPY because it could very well be buried somewhere in there more than once. Take a look just at the first for of your example and the last row. You have to distinguish 1CC and CC1 as both becoming CC. What if you had something like CC1/2/13? Honestly with 10,000 rows it is probably faster and less prone to error to just buckle down and do this manually in Excel. There are just too many possibilities when the data is so scattered.

Comment: looks like something i'd just import into excel separating the column by space and commas and just start working on it

Comment: @PicoDeGallo I see one of your top tags is C# you could make a simple program to handle most cases and tell you what rows it failed on. I'd try to come up with a sql answer but that's beyond my sql skills =)

Comment: @SeanLange Based on @lad2025's answer below, I believe at the very least, I think I can utilize `SUBSTRING` and `PATINDEX` to extract the date for the various date instances and then manually massage the data from there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not task for T-SQL per se. But let's try:

<kbd>**[LiveDemo](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/376176)**</kbd>

```
WITH cte AS
(
   SELECT [Remarks] = REPLACE(REPLACE(Remarks, '-', '.'), '/', '.')
   FROM #mytable
), cte2 AS
(
  SELECT
    Remarks
    ,[Type] = CASE 
              WHEN CHARINDEX('CC', Remarks) > 0 THEN 'CC'
              WHEN CHARINDEX('COPY', Remarks) > 0 THEN 'COPY'
              ELSE NULL
           END
    ,[Date] = CASE 
     WHEN PATINDEX('%[0-9][0-9].[0-9][0-9].[0-9]%', Remarks) > 0 
     THEN SUBSTRING(Remarks, PATINDEX('%[0-9][0-9].[0-9][0-9].[0-9]%', Remarks), 8)

     WHEN PATINDEX('%[0-9][0-9].[0-9].[0-9]%', Remarks) > 0
     THEN SUBSTRING(Remarks, PATINDEX('%[0-9][0-9].[0-9].[0-9]%', Remarks), 7)

     WHEN PATINDEX('%[0-9].[0-9][0-9].[0-9]%', Remarks) > 0
     THEN SUBSTRING(Remarks, PATINDEX('%[0-9].[0-9][0-9].[0-9]%', Remarks), 7)

     WHEN PATINDEX('%[0-9].[0-9].[0-9]%', Remarks) > 0
     THEN SUBSTRING(Remarks, PATINDEX('%[0-9].[0-9].[0-9]%', Remarks), 6)
     ELSE NULL
   END
  FROM cte
)
SELECT *,
  [Date] = DATEFROMPARTS ( PARSENAME([Date], 1)+2000,
                           PARSENAME([Date], 3),
                           PARSENAME([Date], 2))
FROM cte2;
```

**Warning:**

There are cases this code does not handle, this is just demo. For more secure solution you can use `TRY_PARSE` and so on...

In my opinion without human supervision you can't do it with TSQL 100% reliable.

## EDIT:

Handling invalid dates (for invalid date string you will get `NULL`):

<kbd>**[LiveDemo2](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/376193)**</kbd>

```
SELECT *,
[Date] = TRY_PARSE( CONCAT(PARSENAME([Date], 1)+2000, '-', PARSENAME([Date], 3), '-' ,PARSENAME([Date], 2)) AS DATE)
FROM cte2
```

## EDIT2:

Changed `'%[0-9][0-9].[0-9].[0-9]%'` to `'%[0-9][0-9].[0-9].[0-9][0-9]%'`

<kbd>**[LiveDemo3](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/376212)**</kbd>

```
,[Date] = CASE 
  WHEN PATINDEX('%[0-9][0-9].[0-9][0-9].[0-9][0-9]%', Remarks) > 0 THEN SUBSTRING(Remarks, PATINDEX('%[0-9][0-9].[0-9][0-9].[0-9][0-9]%', Remarks), 8)
  WHEN PATINDEX('%[0-9][0-9].[0-9].[0-9][0-9]%', Remarks) > 0 THEN SUBSTRING(Remarks, PATINDEX('%[0-9][0-9].[0-9].[0-9][0-9]%', Remarks), 7)
  WHEN PATINDEX('%[0-9].[0-9][0-9].[0-9][0-9]%', Remarks) > 0 THEN SUBSTRING(Remarks, PATINDEX('%[0-9].[0-9][0-9].[0-9][0-9]%', Remarks), 7)
  WHEN PATINDEX('%[0-9].[0-9].[0-9][0-9]%', Remarks) > 0 THEN SUBSTRING(Remarks, PATINDEX('%[0-9].[0-9].[0-9][0-9]%', Remarks), 6)

  ELSE NULL
  END
```

Comment: While I'm receiving two errors while running it (`Cannot construct data type date, some of the arguments have values which are not valid.`, which upon removal of `DATEFROMPARTS`, I receive the error `Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value '5,' to data type int.` due to junk data, the utilization of `SUBSTRING` and `PATINDEX` is actually incredibly helpful at pulling the various instances of date. As others have noted, there will have to be a significant amount of data massaging, but I'll at least be able to pull a semblance of the date and remove other characters that do not fit.

Comment: @PicoDeGallo Added support for invalid dates, when cannot construct date you will get NULL

Comment: @PicoDeGallo As for second error please provide data sample. I will try to mitigate it.

Comment: Here are two instances of a failed convert. In this first one, it is because of the comma following the 5: `1 CC 02-17-15, 1 COPY 02/18/15` In this instance, it is because of the C following the date 5/4/11C: `1CC 5/4/11/1CC 3-19-12, 1 CC 5-10-13` Thanks much for your assistance, I am tweaking this already and it's working greatly!

Comment: @PicoDeGallo Editted once more, I change regex sligthly and it should work for this 2 cases

Comment: Phenomenal work, that did the trick perfectly. I am able to bring back all the rows without any issue. I am going to further analyze the data closely to ensure things are being brought back appropriately, but this has saved me hours of work. Thank you again!

Comment: @PicoDeGallo One more thing handle dates before 2000, like 98 because you will get 2098 like:  `IIF(PARSENAME([Date], 1)> 20, PARSENAME([Date], 1) + 1900, PARSENAME([Date], 1) + 2000)`

Comment: I noticed that, and also when there are full years such as 6.28.2011, it is not transforming appropriately. I will make the necessary adjustments.

Comment: @PicoDeGallo Just add more WHEN to case, for handling 2 and 4 digit year. Good luck with extending it for your needs. If more assistance needed maybe ask new question :)